# How to fix errors when run pip in dockerfile?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, pipenv, appdynamics

I am trying to build a docker image and push it to AWS ECS. I am currently integrating an API with appdynamics. I need to issue a command to pip to start a proxy before the app opens. When running locally I do this with `pyagent proxy start` and it works fine. The problem comes when using that command with docker. When I attempt to use that command during the build and push process I get the following error stack.

```
Ignoring appdynamics-bindeps-osx-x64: markers 'sys_platform == "darwin" and (platform_machine == "x86_64" or platform_machine == "AMD64")' don't match your environment
Ignoring appdynamics-proxysupport-osx-x64: markers 'sys_platform == "darwin" and (platform_machine == "x86_64" or platform_machine == "AMD64")' don't match your environment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyagent", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/appdynamics/scripts/pyagent/pyagent.py", line 66, in main
    mod.command(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/appdynamics/scripts/pyagent/commands/proxy.py", line 69, in command
    SUBCOMMANDS[subcommand](args[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/appdynamics/scripts/pyagent/commands/proxy.py", line 131, in start
    copy_cert_to_proxy_dir(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/appdynamics/scripts/pyagent/commands/proxy.py", line 114, in copy_cert_to_proxy_dir
    proxysupport_dir = get_proxysupport_dir()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/appdynamics/scripts/pyagent/commands/proxy.py", line 109, in get_proxysupport_dir
    return [e for e in sys.path if 'site-packages' in e][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip &&     pip3 install pipenv --upgrade &&     pipenv install --ignore-pipfile --system && pyagent proxy start' returned a non-zero code: 1
Error response from daemon: No such image: myimage:latest
```

I run the app locally from mac and install the package to a pipfile on a mac. I know that darwin corresponds to macOS. Is this an issue because docker runs Linux or another issue I missing. The markers the error traces says it is ignoring appear in the pipfile.lock.  I would like some aid in understanding what the error means and any help is appreciated!

Thank you!